# Spring comma separated list of bean references

Tags: java, spring

In Spring, is it possible to feed a comma separated list of bean references into another bean, ideally without any custom property editors. This list comes from a placeholder that I have no control over.

For example (does not work):

```
<bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.Integer />
<bean id="bean2" class="java.lang.Integer />

<bean class="customclass">
  <constructor-arg><ref bean="bean1,bean2" /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Which would be identical to:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.Integer />
<bean id="bean2" class="java.lang.Integer />

<bean class="customclass">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <ref bean="bean1"/>
      <ref bean="bean2"/>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm willing to bet that is not supported. On the other hand, you could write a little bit of code that takes that String of bean IDs, splits it on the comma, and then gets each one out of the ApplicationContext by ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible using this approach:

Consider a properties file with entries like this:

`test.properties`:

```
beanlist1=#{{@bean1,@bean2}}
```

Now you will be able to do this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="test.properties"/>
<bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.Integer />
<bean id="bean2" class="java.lang.Integer />

<bean class="customclass">
  <constructor-arg value="${beanlist}></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

which is fairly close to what you want(slightly different representation - `#{{@bean1,@bean2}}` instead of `bean1,bean2`) .

Another way is the following:

```
<bean class="customclass">
  <constructor-arg value="#{{@bean1,@bean2}}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Both work using the Spring-EL expression to represent a list.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but it would be easy enough to write a factory bean to do it for you. It would need to take the comma separated string as a property, split it, and return a `ManagedList` containing a `RuntimeBeanReference` for each name. This could then be injected into other beans in the usual way and the references would be resolved in the way you require.